# UIView animation on iPad doesn't take into account orientation

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to slide my main view controller view to the right when the user taps a button.  I use this code:

```
   [UIView  animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^(void){ self.view.left = 300; }
                     completion:nil];
```

The result is that view.frame.origin.x does not take into account device orientation.  If the screen is landscape left, then setting x = 300 does not move the view to the right, it moves it down.  I could do a big switch statement to change the relevant parameter depending on orientation but I feel like I've done this before without having to resort to such shenanigans. Am I missing something obvious?

I've tried with no options, no difference.

I'm using a category on UIView so that I don't have to type out the entire CGRectMake explicitly.  The results are the same if I do it with the full CGRectMake statement.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Animating the view's bounds instead of the view's frame (I am assuming this is what the category is doing) worked for me.